# How to export path to compute nodes, parallel programming

Tags: linux, bash, mpi, intel-fortran

I have a problem using ifort.  I compiled a code with ifort/mpich1 but whenever I try to run it across several nodes the code gets to a certain point and hangs with an error:

```
symbol lookup error ... undefined symbol __svml_round2
```

In poking around, I'm pretty sure this is due to to the ifortvars shell script not being sourced on the compute nodes (if I try to fire the code serially on one node, but haven't sourced the ifort vars I get the same exact error).

What is the best way to bypass this problem?  It seems my ".bashrc" file isn't executed when running through mpirun, since I have the "source ..." command in the .bashrc file.  I also tried adding the line to the /etc/bash.bashrc file but got no luck.  Alternatively I thought perhaps static linking when I compile would solve the problem so I included

```
-i-static
-static
```

when compiling with ifort but to no avail, I still get the error.

Does anyone know how to bypass this problem, essentially either how to compile with ifort so as not not need to "source ifortvars" when running a compiled program (a more desirable solution), or how to push out either my path, or how to source the vars through an MPI call?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can give environmental variables as part of the mpirun/mpirun_rsh  command.

e.g.

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib;mpirun_rsh -ssh -host -np 2  -hostfile hostlist   /home/usr1/app.exe -x /home/usr1/config/appconfig.xml`